# Getting rpi_ws281x library up and running in c++

Tags: c++, led

I am trying to get this library [jgarff/rpi_ws281x](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x) up and running and installed it as described in the readme.md

When running the python examples the stripe works as expected but I don't get the C++ code up and running.

Here is what I am trying:

```
    #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <rpi_ws281x/ws2811.h>
#include <cstdint>

/*
    Defines für ws2811 LED Stripes
*/

#define TARGET_FREQ                             WS2811_TARGET_FREQ
#define GPIO_PIN                                18
#define DMA                                     5
#define STRIP_TYPE                              WS2811_STRIP_RGB        // WS2812/SK6812RGB integrated chip+leds
//#define STRIP_TYPE                            WS2811_STRIP_GBR        // WS2812/SK6812RGB integrated chip+leds
//#define STRIP_TYPE                            SK6812_STRIP_RGBW       // SK6812RGBW (NOT SK6812RGB)
#define LED_COUNT                               10

ws2811_led_t dotcolors[] =
{
    0x00200000,  // red
    0x00201000,  // orange
    0x00202000,  // yellow
    0x00002000,  // green
    0x00002020,  // lightblue
    0x00000020,  // blue
    0x00100010,  // purple
    0x00200010,  // pink
};

ws2811_led_t dotcolors_rgbw[] =
{
    0x00200000,  // red
    0x10200000,  // red + W
    0x00002000,  // green
    0x10002000,  // green + W
    0x00000020,  // blue
    0x10000020,  // blue + W
    0x00101010,  // white
    0x10101010,  // white + W

};

ws2811_t ledstring =
{
    nullptr,
    TARGET_FREQ,
    DMA,

    0, GPIO_PIN, 0, LED_COUNT, 255, STRIP_TYPE,
    0

};

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    ws2811_init(&ledstring);

    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < LED_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (ledstring.channel[0].strip_type == SK6812_STRIP_RGBW) {
            ledstring.channel[0].leds[i] = dotcolors_rgbw[c];
        }
        else {
            ledstring.channel[0].leds[i] = dotcolors[c];
        }
        
        c++;
        
        ws2811_render(&ledstring);

        if (c == sizeof(dotcolors))
        {
            c = 0;
        }

        usleep(1000000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine (using -fpermissive) and runs without errors - but all LEDs stay dark :(

I don't see any issues and wonder what I am doing wrong??

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue myself and discovered that the initialization of the ledstrig struct was wrong.

The correct one needs to look like this:

```
ws2811_t ledstring =
{
    0,
    0,
    TARGET_FREQ,
    DMA,

    GPIO_PIN, 0, LED_COUNT, 125, STRIP_TYPE,
    0

};
```

I still don't understand how this initialization works - but at least this one gives the right values in the reqired fields.

Comment: I know this is old, very old. I have some code in cpp that I want to include that library in, I am not cpp programmer so probably that's where the issue is. But, 
I've managed include library, and define ledstring. 
But I get `undefined reference to ws2811_init`  when compiling, what am I doing wrong?